# Auto-refresh GSheet formulas that use BQ data when editing other cells

Tags: google-apps-script

Using an =sumifs statement in a Google Sheet to compile values within a linked BQ table. That formula works fine, looking across dates and other variables that can be changed in the Google Sheet. However, every time a change is made the =sumifs cell requires a manual push of an 'Apply' button to recalculate the value based on the changed variables.

An AppScript can fix one cell every time an edit is made anywhere within the Google Sheet. But, first, I need to constrain it to only respond to edits within that particular tab/sheet (it's called 'Velocity Report'), not the entire workbook. And second, I need the AppScript to recalculate for every cell in column M, not just M5.

The basic recorded macro for fixing cell M5 is below (works fine for fixing cell M5), but I'm unsure of how to adapt it based on the above requirements.

```
function VelocityReportBQRefresh() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('M5').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceFormulas()[0].refreshData();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function VelocityReportBQRefresh(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Velocity Report') {
    //your code
  }
}
```